# CakePHP 3.0 - Virtual property missing on production server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a strange issue with CakePHP 3.0 and virtual properties on our server.
We have a Photo Entity with the following virtual property:

```
protected function _getPath()
{
    [...]

    return $path; // array with path for different photo sizes
}
```

On our development server (Ubuntu, Apache, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6) everything works perfectly.
On our production server (Linux, Apache, PHP 5.5.23) the site is working great, except that the virtual properties are missing in the data object.

The photo entity is read from db via Entries Table->contain and echoed like this:

```
$entry->photos[0]['path']['wide'];
```

The basic properties of the Photo entity can be read on both servers with e.g.:

```
$entry->photos[0]['filename'];
```

In addition I just found out, that a pr() on $entry->photo[0] (or $photo in foreach loop) is different on both servers.
On the server where everything works as expected i get:

```
App\Model\Entity\Photo Object
(
    [_accessible:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 1
            [filename] => 1
            [org_name] => 1
            [description] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [entry] => 1
        )

    [_virtual:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => path
        )
[...]
```

and on the server where the virtual property is missing i get:

```
Cake\ORM\Entity Object
(
    [_properties:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 37
            [user_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 4
            [filename] => p19fng7349bb2p6nsac14j51qnu4.jpg
[...]
```

Any idea why the virtual property on the production environment is missing, and why the objects on both servers are of different types?

Thanks a lot!

Simon

Comment: The entity class being an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Entity` indicates that the actual table and/or entity file/class could not be found (if you debug the table instance it might be an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of `\App\Model\Table\PhotosTable`). Make sure that the files exist, that they are readable, that the file- and classnames follow the naming conventions, that the autoloader is configured and dumped correctly, and there's probably more that I can't think of right now.

Comment: Thx for your comment. What confuses me is, that the files on both servers are identical. No cache is active, autoloader is configured.
Also strange is, that another Model is wiorking fine, including the virtual properties. I also tried renaming the property from path to url, with no luck.

Comment: Even though no cache is active, maybe removing the temp cache files in the temp folder just to make sure (tmp/cache/models). Also make sure your database schema is up to date on all machines, as a matter of fact, copy the database and application code and setup locally just to make sure it works on a different machine to make sure.