# Cakephp 3.0 not saving Entity, no error/s... what's going on?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
$newContainer = $this->Containers->newEntity($this->request->data);
if($this->Containers->save($newContainer) !== false)
{
    $this->Flash->success("Saved"); 
}
else
{
    debug($newContainer);
}
```

It's always display the debug, but there are no validation errors.

Debug output:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'new' => true,
    'accessible' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'Container' => [
            'name' => 'Test2',
            'description' => 'test',
            'slug' => '',
            'thumbnail_image_url' => '',
            'preview_video_image_url' => '',
            'preview_video_url' => '',
            'is_private' => '',
            'index_weight' => '',
            'custom_layout' => '',
            'custom_view' => ''
        ]
    ],
    'dirty' => [
        'Container' => true
    ],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'Containers'

}
```

and obviously, there is no new record actually being created in the database...

Anyone have an ideas what is going on?

Comment: An explicit [**entity class is missing**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275998/cakephp-3-0-virtual-property-missing-on-production-server#comment46771059_29275998), and your request data is formatted incorrectly. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs**

Comment: You are correct with the request data. I was using Container.name, etc as form fields name like I used to with 2.X -- new forms must be field name only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cake 2.x you could use Model.field name as your form inputs, in 3.0 this causes issues and does not work, use field name only for form inputs.

```
$this->Form->input("Model.name"); // Wrong
$this->Form->input("name"); // Correct
```

Comment: What if I have a Form that will have fields from 2 different models ?